# Can I get an element from a List<T> by string-based indexing in .Net? (I.E.: T val = List<T>["NameHere"])

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, properties

In C#/.Net, I know that with a `DataSet` you can access a named table by `DataSet.Tables[NameHere]`.

Is it possible to do this with a List (if the elements in the list have a property by which you can find them like that?)

I'm not talking about `List<T>.Find(tVar => tVar.Prop == "NameHere")`,

I want to just be able to say `T val = List<T>["NameHere"]`.

Is that possible, and if so, how would I go about accomplishing this?

Also, as a kind of aside, I'm sure this has a proper name : What is it?

Comment: No you can't, you will need a dictionary for that. Think of `List` as of an advanced `array`

Comment: Okay, then returning to the DataSet.Tables point, how would I go about implementing a generic collection by which I could reference values by name?

Comment: Isn't this just a [`Dictionary<string, T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or do you want something more?

Comment: Why do you need a List of the Dictionary is what you seek?

Comment: I'm not looking for a dictionary. I have a class with a string property, and another class which keeps a list of that class. I would like to be able to say Class1["Class2Name"] and get the Class 2 value. Anyway, evidently that's called indexing, and Eugen was able to point me in the correct direction.

Comment: @Will there is already an implementation that does that. If you want to use the existing thing, look into `KeyedCollection`.

Comment: @Frank yeah that looks closer to what I want... though I was able to get where I needed to go by creating a class based on List<T>{
    public T this[string index]{ get { return this.defaultifempty(null).firstordefault(T.name == index); } }
}

Comment: @Will That will probably work, but it will search your list by comparing each item in it. For big lists, performance will be worse than using hashes, which KeyedCollection or Dictionary do internally.

Comment: @Frank Okay, but will that support both integer and string based indexing?

Comment: @Frank Also, I need it to be able to support methods that Lists can do, like AddRange.

Comment: @Will Then you should probably roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "indexer", read more from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)

You can create your own class which implement IList interface and add indexer to it.

Comment: That's exactly for what I was looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `KeyedCollection<TKey,TValue>` for your type:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClassCollection : KeyedCollection<string,SomeClass>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(SomeClass item)
    {
        return item.Name;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class KeyedCollectionTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var items = new SomeClassCollection
                    {
                        new SomeClass{Name = "Name 1", Value = "Value 1"},
                        new SomeClass{Name = "Name 2", Value = "Value 2"}
                    };

        items["Name 1"].Value.Should().Be("Value 1");
        items[1].Value.Should().Be("Value 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Will You will add additional complication to your code base by rolling your own apart from any performance impact. I reckon your problem can be solved by utilising existing functions in .Net

There are 2 ways to solve your problem

1. Using List to point to your set of objects to allow you to index by int AND
   Using a Dictionary to point to the same set of objects to allow you to index my string. An object can be reference by more than one collection
2. Using a DataTable with an Int column and a string column, put an index on each column and use the Find function. (Not sure if you could add an index on each columns like a db table as I haven't use DataTable for a long time but I'm sure you can look up MSDN documentation)